# JavaScript: Event listener on iFrame resize / height attribute change (FB comment box)

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have the following problem: I need to add an event listener for an `iframe` (a Facebook comment box) when it changes its height.

I can not access or change the `contentWindow` because it is cross domain. But there must be a callback function or something that changes the `height` attribute.

Is there a way to add an event listener on attribute changes or something? I alreade tried onResize and onChange.

I'm getting crazy with that... Anyone has an idea?

Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No.

However, you can use "postMessage" and "receiveMessage" to send from one iframe to another cross domain. (Of course, only if you have access to the iframed content - I suspect not as it's on facebook.)

In any case... for future help....

(on the iframed page)

```
var ii = {}
ii.window_height = 800;
var sendHeight = function () {
        var window_height = $('body').outerHeight(true);
        if (window_height != ii.window_height) {
        ii.window_height = window_height;
        window.parent.postMessage(ii.window_height, "http://containerDomain.com");
    }
}
setInterval(sendHeight, 2000);
```

(on the container page)

```
function receiveMessage(evt) {
  if (evt.origin === 'https://iframedDomain.com')
  {
    var iframe_content_height = evt.data;
    $('#iframe_form').animate({height: iframe_content_height });
  }
}

if ($.browser.msie) {
window.attachEvent('onmessage', receiveMessage);    
} else {
window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage, false);
}
```

Remember to change the domains in each script.

Note: that's using jQuery - It works, but I'm sure someone can write that better then me? Also not too proud of the interval checking the height... might update if i can.